# Can I make an alias for `set -l` in the fish shell?

Tags: shell, fish

I make liberal use of `set -l`/`set --local` in my fish scripts, so I considered making an alias for it. The name `local` seems apt. Unfortunately, the obvious approach doesn't work:

```
function local
  set -l $argv
end
```

This fails because, of course, the variable this creates is *local* to the `local` function itself. Using `alias` doesn't work, either, since it's just a (perhaps legacy) shorthand for the above function.

Is there any way I can create a local variable in the calling scope without doing anything more complicated than `local foo 'bar'`? Obviously I could make something like `eval (local foo 'bar')` work, but that would sort of defeat the purpose. I'm open to any sort of trickery or hacks that would make this work, if any exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not, local variables are always local to the topmost scope, and there's no way to wrap `set` without creating a new scope. The best you can do is this:

```
function def --no-scope-shadowing
    set $argv 
end
```

This creates a variable in the calling function scope. This is subtly different than local: local is scoped to a block, while the above is scoped  to the function. Still it may be sufficient for your use case.

Comment: Ah, well. That's more or less what I suspected, but it's nice to know for sure. The example you gave doesn't do much since it's *identical* to plain `set`, but that's fine. Thanks for the official response!